# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, android-asynctask

i connect to AWS(Amazon WebService) and read data from specific table
and from within data S3Link object used this object to return image for each item
some image not return because SocketTimeoutException

```
    @Override
    protected List<Item> doInBackground(Void... params) {

        itemList= ItemOperation.getItemList();      // get data from Amazon

        Log.e(TAG,itemList.size()+"");
        return itemList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Item> items) {
        new DownloadImage().execute(items);
    }
}

public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<List<Item>,Void,Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(List<Item>... params) {

        AmazonS3Client s3Client=new AmazonS3Client(Constants.MANAGER.getCredentials());
        InputStream myObjectBytes=null;
        S3Object getResponse=null;
        GetObjectRequest getRequest;
        for (int i=0;i<params[0].size();i++) {
            String bucketName= params[0].get(i).getItemPhoto1().getBucketName();
            String pictureId= params[0].get(i).getItemPhoto1().getKey();
            getRequest = new GetObjectRequest(bucketName,pictureId);
            getResponse = s3Client.getObject(getRequest);
            myObjectBytes = getResponse.getObjectContent();
            itemList.get(i).setBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(myObjectBytes));
        }
        try {
            myObjectBytes.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }
```

Exception and image don't download because of `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`:

```
08-28 21:06:20.576      709-755/com.sprintone I/art? Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 48266(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 16(444KB) LOS objects, 0% free, 21MB/21MB, paused 1.345ms total 103.715ms
08-28 21:07:04.413     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
08-28 21:07:04.414     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
08-28 21:07:04.414     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:699)
08-28 21:07:04.414     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:113)
08-28 21:07:04.414     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:48)
08-28 21:07:04.415     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:446)
08-28 21:07:04.415     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
08-28 21:07:04.415     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
08-28 21:07:04.415     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
08-28 21:07:04.415     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at java.security.DigestInputStream.read(DigestInputStream.java:113)
08-28 21:07:04.416     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.DigestValidationInputStream.read(DigestValidationInputStream.java:60)
08-28 21:07:04.416     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.amazonaws.internal.SdkFilterInputStream.read(SdkFilterInputStream.java:73)
08-28 21:07:04.416     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
08-28 21:07:04.416     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStreamInternal(BitmapFactory.java:635)
08-28 21:07:04.416     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:611)
08-28 21:07:04.425     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:649)
08-28 21:07:04.431     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.sprintone.userInterface.Fragment.FirstTabFragment$DownloadImage.doInBackground(FirstTabFragment.java:121)
08-28 21:07:04.432     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at com.sprintone.userInterface.Fragment.FirstTabFragment$DownloadImage.doInBackground(FirstTabFragment.java:107)
08-28 21:07:04.432     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
08-28 21:07:04.432     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-28 21:07:04.434     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-28 21:07:04.435     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-28 21:07:04.436     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-28 21:07:04.437     709-1541/com.sprintone W/System.err? at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-28 21:07:04.437     709-1541/com.sprintone D/skia? ---- read threw an exception
08-28 21:07:04.437     709-1541/com.sprintone D/skia? --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Comment: Could you please post an example stack trace?

Comment: this exception found in my logcat

Comment: Please format your stack trace as code. It is illegible at present.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet?  What kind of connection are you using?  Is it switching network types?  Are you using the latest version of the SDK?  I don't see anything particularly odd about your code.

Comment: yes i'm connect the internet   kind of connection WIFI
i can't understand this question Is it switching network types?

Comment: @WestonE for my code that is correct or there is a problem in it

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your s3 code, but there could be factors outside of those few lines that could affect the connection.

Comment: can you help me when load image use this code
load is slow what reason ? @WestonE

Comment: Can you please answer " Are you sure you are connected to the internet? What kind of connection are you using? Is it switching network types? Are you using the latest version of the SDK? "

Comment: @bytecode77 Please use code formatting for text that is code or computer output.

Answer (score 1):

The default connection timeout and socket timeout are both 15 seconds. See [source on Github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.java). If your network connection is relatively poor, consider increase the timeout via [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html).

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setConnectionTimeout(60 * 1000); // 60 sec
config.setSocketTimeout(60 * 1000); // 60 sec
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Constants.MANAGER.getCredentials(), config);
```

Comment: i want to download more images from amazon S3 and show them in ResycleView more efficient 
help me to do it @Yangfan

Comment: What is not efficient? PS: This will be a separate question. I suggest you create a new question to draw more attentions.